# Colocar una Cards de bootstrap una al lado de la otra

Tags: css, bootstrap

Bueno la verdad soy muy novato en esto y tengo miles de problemas,pero basicamente lo q no puedo hacer es colocar un cards bootstrap una al lado del otro,trate de mil formas y no queda,siempre queda uno debajo del otro...

```css
.header{
    background-color: transparent  !important;
    background: url(imagenes/Costa-Rica.jpg) fixed center;
     background-size: cover; 
     min-height: 650px;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px
     
}

.mi-navbar{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0 ,0.5) 
}



  

    .fotos1 img{
        height: 650px;
                       }
        

   
    .carrusel{
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
                     }

      .texto h5{
          color: white;
      }



      

    .comida{
        background: url(imagenes/pinches-cocineros.jpg);
         background-size: cover; 
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top:  50px;
        display: inline-block;
        
    }

     


.cards{
 
     color: white;
       
     background-color: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.4) 
}

.ceviche{
    margin-left: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <title>El lugar donde queres viajar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
                                          <!-- NAVBAR -->



        <header id="inicio" class="header">

          
          <nav class="mi-navbar navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand text-primary ml-4" href="#">Costa <span class="text-danger">Rica</span>  </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="casa navbar-nav m-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light mr-5" href="#inicio">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li> 
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-light mr-5" href="#turismo">Turismo</a>
                   
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-light mr-5" href="#comida">Comidas</a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-light mr-5" href="index4.html">Hoteleria</a>
                    </li>
                  
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light mr-5" href="index5.html">Nosotros</a>
                  </li>
                  
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>

            <div>

                <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                    <div class="toast-header">
                      <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
                      <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
                      <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
                      <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toast-body">
                      See? Just like this.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   </header>
                  
              
            
                   <section class="publicidad">

                   <div></div>


                   </section>
         


                     <!-- CARRUSEL -->
                     <section id="turismo">

                   <div class="carrusel">

                  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>

                      
                      <div class="fotos1 carousel-inner texto">

                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                         <img src="imagenes/costarica-volcan.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                           
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                              <h5>Volcan Arenal</h5>
                               <p>Una de las razones princiaples de viajar a Costa Rica, <br> es conocer su magnifica naturaleza,y sus increibles parques nacionales protegidos!</p>
                                </div>

                                  </div> 


                           
                                   <div class="carousel-item">
                                     <img src="imagenes/costa-rica-4.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid bg-dark" alt="...">
                                 <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                        <h5>Puntarena</h5>
                                         <p>
                                            Puntarenas es una ciudad portuaria en el Golfo de Nicoya, en Costa Rica. Su Casa de la Cultura alberga un teatro y una galería de arte. En la avenida principal, Paseo de los Turistas, el Parque Marino del Pacífico posee un acuario y un centro de rescate con caballos de mar, tortugas y cocodrilos. La playa de la ciudad, llamada Playa Puntarenas, cuenta con tiendas y cafeterías. Al sudeste, se encuentra Playa Doña Ana, conocida por su fuerte oleaje.</p>
                                           </div>
                                             </div>
        
                                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                          <img src="imagenes/costaricamonte.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                              <h5>Monteverde</h5>
                                                <p>Monteverde es una población situada en la zona montañosa del noroeste de Costa Rica. Es conocida por la biodiversidad de sus bosques nubosos. La famosa Reserva Biológica del Bosque Nuboso de Monteverde alberga un sinfín de especies silvestres, como jaguares, ocelotes y esplendorosos quetzales con plumas de colores. Los senderos señalizados de la reserva atraviesan campos de helechos y orquídeas, y, por arriba, hay puentes colgantes para pasear por encima de la cubierta forestal.</p>
                                                  </div>
                                                   
                                                    </div>
                                                
                                                     </div>
                                                     
                                                     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                                       <span class="flecha carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                       <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                                                         </a>
                               
                                                     <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                                       <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                       <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
                                                     </a>
                                                   </div>
                                                
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     
                                                     
                                                          </section> 

                                     <!-- COMIDA -->
                                                     
                                                          <section id="comida" class="comida">
                                                                
                                                              <div class=" card ml-5 text-center bg-transparent border-0" style= "width: 20rem;">
                                                                  <img src="imagenes/costa-rica-casado.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-circle" alt="...">
                                                                  <div class="card-body cards ">
                                                                    <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Casado</h5>
                                                                    <p class="card-text">Casado o comida típica, es el plato más común en Costa Rica. <br> Se compone de frijoles, arroz con pimientos rojos finamente cortados en cubitos y cebollas, plátanos fritos, una ensalada de repollo con tomate y zanahoria, y una selección de carne entre pollo, pescado, carne de cerdo o de ternera con cebollas asadas.</p>
                                                                     <p id="parrafo" style="display: none;" >La carne que viene con un casado a la parrilla o salteados, pero nunca frito. A veces, el casado incluye papas fritas o verduras adicionales, tales como los aguacates.</p>
                                                                    <a href="#" id="boton" class="btn btn-secondary">Leer Mas...</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                </div>  
                                                                                                                                  <div class=" card ml-5 text-center bg-transparent border-0 d-flex" style= "width: 20rem;">
                                                                                                                                      <img src="imagenes/ceviche.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-circle" alt="...">
                                                                                                                                      <div class="card-body cards ">
                                                                                                                                        <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Ceviche</h5>
                                                                                                                                        <p class="card-text">El ceviche es un aperitivo que consiste en pescado crudo fresco marinado en jugos cítricos como limón con hierbas finamente picadas y verduras. En Costa Rica, el mejor ceviche está hecho con tilapia local o corvina (lubina blanco) y el cilantro, el ajo, el ají, la cebolla y el apio.</p>
                                                                                                                                         <p id="parrafo" style="display: none;" >La carne que viene con un casado a la parrilla o salteados, pero nunca frito. A veces, el casado incluye papas fritas o verduras adicionales, tales como los aguacates.</p>
                                                                                                                                        <a href="#" id="boton" class="btn btn-secondary">Leer Mas...</a>
                                              
                                                        
                                                                                  </section>


                                                                    
                                                                 
                                                                
                                                  
                                                              
                                                                             </div>
                                                                           </div>
                                                                         </div>                                                         
                                                                                                   
                                                      
                                           
                                        
                                 
                                 
                                 

                                               
                                    
                                    

                                      
                                               


              
           
     
     
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="prueba.js"> </script>






<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#boton").click(function(){
     $("#parrafo").toggle(5);
     });
    });
    </script>





    


    <script>
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});</script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: buenos días, primero no esta utilizando los componentes de Bootstrap, Bootstrap en un marco HTML y CSS, segundo le sugiero que lea la utilización de columnas, lo que yo veo es la falta practica de framework y le recomiendo que vea videos  : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/  y https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la clase **[.cols](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)** de bootstrap para seccionar los divs según gustes de la siguiente forma

```css
.header{
    background-color: transparent  !important;
    background: url(imagenes/Costa-Rica.jpg) fixed center;
     background-size: cover; 
     min-height: 650px;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px
     
}

.mi-navbar{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0 ,0.5) 
}



  

    .fotos1 img{
        height: 650px;
                       }
        

   
    .carrusel{
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
                     }

      .texto h5{
          color: white;
      }



      

    .comida{
        background: url(imagenes/pinches-cocineros.jpg);
         background-size: cover; 
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top:  50px;
        display: inline-block;
        
    }

     


.cards{
 
     color: white;
       
     background-color: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.4) 
}

.ceviche{
    margin-left: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="comida" class="comida">                                                                
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card ml-5 text-center bg-transparent border-0 col-md-6" style= "width: 20rem;">
        <img src="imagenes/costa-rica-casado.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-circle" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body cards ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Casado</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Casado o comida típica, es el plato más común en Costa Rica. <br> Se compone de frijoles, arroz con pimientos rojos finamente cortados en cubitos y cebollas, plátanos fritos, una ensalada de repollo con tomate y zanahoria, y una selección de carne entre pollo, pescado, carne de cerdo o de ternera con cebollas asadas.</p>
          <p id="parrafo" style="display: none;" >La carne que viene con un casado a la parrilla o salteados, pero nunca frito. A veces, el casado incluye papas fritas o verduras adicionales, tales como los aguacates.</p>
          <a href="#" id="boton" class="btn btn-secondary">Leer Mas...</a>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="card ml-5 text-center bg-transparent border-0 d-flex col-md-6" style= "width: 20rem;">
        <img src="imagenes/ceviche.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-circle" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body cards ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Ceviche</h5>
          <p class="card-text">El ceviche es un aperitivo que consiste en pescado crudo fresco marinado en jugos cítricos como limón con hierbas finamente picadas y verduras. En Costa Rica, el mejor ceviche está hecho con tilapia local o corvina (lubina blanco) y el cilantro, el ajo, el ají, la cebolla y el apio.</p>
          <p id="parrafo" style="display: none;" >La carne que viene con un casado a la parrilla o salteados, pero nunca frito. A veces, el casado incluye papas fritas o verduras adicionales, tales como los aguacates.</p>
          <a href="#" id="boton" class="btn btn-secondary">Leer Mas...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero el problema no es únicamente que no está haciendo uso de las columnas propias de Bootstrap, sino que su código original tiene varios errores de escritura, por ejemplo, muchas etiquetas `div` sin cierre

Comment: ahh ok muchas gracias... vos pensas q por la falta de etiquetas de cierres puede pasar esto? hay alguna forma de darme cuenta q etiqueta es la q falta cerrar? disculpa las molestias,desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ahi estuve viendo bien tu codigo y yo tambien hice uso de la cuadricula (no se si asi se dice) de bootstrap pero me quedaba igual... lo q vi,es q yo usaba el div-container y el div-row no se si el container era el q no dejaba a los demas divs colocarse uno al lado del otro... Muchas gracias en serio y disculpa por hacerle perder el tiempo!

Comment: @IvanLeiva96 lo mejor que puedes hacer para corroborar cada etiqueta es maquetar el HTML de nuevo para evitar que te marees con tanto código; realiza eso y comentanos si sigue igual para orientarte si lo necesitas colega :)

Comment: Ok Paulo muchísimas gracias,voy a hacer eso,pero antes veré un curso de flexbox asi tengo mejor noción de lo q hago y no solo copio código sin entender... de nuevo muchas gracias y ojala haya mas gente amable como vos en este rubro.Un abrazo!

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo presente que la estructura HTML tiene etiquetas sin cerrar puedes utilizar FLEXBOX (cajas flexibles). Indiferente de que trabajes con Bootstrap puedes tener un contenedor principal que encierre las CARDS que necesites y agregando la etiqueta display:flex, los elementos hijos del contenedor se posicionaran uno al lado de otro.

EJM:

```css
.contenedor
{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex !important; / ETIQUETA QUE POSICIONA UNO AL LADO DEL OTRO */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contenedor .hijo 
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.contenedor .hijo1
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="hijo">Hijo 1</div>
  <div class="hijo1">Hijo 2</div>
</di>
```

De recomendación utilizar flexbox en lo más Posible.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme... Hice lo q me dijiste y sigue igual! y vos pensas q me falta cerrar alguna etiqueta por eso me esta pasando esto?